# How could I have an mysql parameter as an array when not using php?

Tags: mysql

I'm not really familiar with mySQL but I'm trying to create a stored procedure which is linked to a table in a database (that I can't change), it's actually looking like this:

```
create procedure getMesuresBetweenDates (in startDate timestamp , in endDate timestamp , in waspmoteName varchar(16) , in sensorName varchar(16), out result) -- it  has to be a table/array which contain the sensorName and the timestamp 
    begin
        If startDate >= endDate then return(-2);
        If not exists (select * from sensorParser) then return(-1);
        set @countOfRow = NULL;
        select @countOfRow=count(*) value, timestamp from sensorParser where id_wasp = waspmoteName and sensor = sensorName and timestamp >= startDate and timestamp <= endDate;
        if @countOfRow=0 then return(0);
        -- and that's here I need an array to stock datas
        result = select value, timestamp from sensorParser where id_wasp = waspmoteName and sensor = sensorName and timestamp >= startDate and timestamp <= endDate;
        return(@countOfRow)
    end;
```

What should I do?

Comment: What do you want to do with that array (AKA Table in SQL) ?

Comment: I have to give it to someone who is developping a WPF application in link this the database, so I have to make it as easy as possible, because he will have a lot of work

Comment: @Cid do you have any idea how I could do?

Comment: @Cid ? do you know someone that could help ?